# what the classname like [C [B [[C is,when i exec "jmap -histo:live 4984"?

Tags: jvm, classname, jmap

And is always has most instances, just like this

```
  enter codnum     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:         82828       10033408  [C
   2:         39920        6012864  [B
   3:         18752        1950208  org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarEntry
   4:         81007        1944168  java.lang.String
   5:         16542        1455696  java.lang.reflect.Method
   6:         37512        1200384  org.springframework.boot.loader.util.AsciiBytes
   7:         18752        1050112  org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarEntryData
```

Comment: These are JVM signatures for `char[]`, `byte[]` and `char[][]` classes respectively.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--

Answer (score 1):

already has answer in comments

These are JVM signatures for char[], byte[] and char[][] classes respectively. – apangin
[docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/…](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) – Holger

Comment: So do most of the  [C allocations actually come from the implementation of String?